# Centering the navigation brand title/ logo

Tags: html, css, material-design

I am practicing and learning the new material design lite css framework and I read and scanned their site but I can't get the solution on how can I center the navigation title. If anyone knows how to do it, can you give me a sample fix?
This is my code so far.

HTML:

```
<!-- Title -->
 <span class="mdl-layout-title navbar">Title</span>
```

Note: I added a .navbar class so that I can override the style.

CSS:

```
.navbar {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```

The logo is now centered but the links are pushed to the right and some of the links can be read.

The screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position: absolute` and `transform: translate()`

```css
nav {
  position: relative;
  background: #2196F3;
  height: 50px;
}
.mdl-layout-title {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <span class="mdl-layout-title navbar">Title</span>
</nav>
```

Comment: Tried this one but the brand title pushed below the nav.

Comment: Have you set `position: relative` on parent?

Comment: awe, thanks it works now but the there's another issue. When opening the side drawer, brand title pushed down

Comment: Fixed now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
.navbar {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;

}
```

Comment: This can be also useful but need to increase the top value.